# Hybris addons install concept

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, add-on

How is the best way to work with a default `Hybris addon`? There are some really nice addon features we want to use in our projects, but of course not exactly the way they are. So what is the best practice to modify them?

Is it the way to copy the addon into the own project and then handle it as an own addon? (So put it under the 'custom' folder and modify it as needed)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How is the best way to work with a default addon from hybris?

Addons are used to extend Hybris platform functionalities without
changing its source code, they are standard extensions, So,
I think that the best way is to **create your own addon**, so you keep your 
code independent of Hybris business logic and modular for future evolution.
In general SAP Hybris recommends the extension of its code without modifying it.

> What exactly happens by installing an addon on an extension?

Once you execute the following command :

```
ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="myAddOn" -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="myStorefront"
```

ant addoninstall will :

- Add myAddOn into extensioninfo.xml as required
  for myStorefront  extension
- Add myAddOn to addons.less for myStorefront
- Generate a new project.properties file from the project.properties.template inside myAddOn.
- Configure the myAddOn web spring configuration
  myAddOn-web-spring.xml into myStorefront.additionalWebSpringConfigs

> When need to uninstall an addon, does it need to use the uninstall
>   command?

Yes, you need to execute ant addonuninstall in order to rollback the actions listed in the second response.

Comment: Thanks for your answears. But with your first answear i would disagree, because the point is, that the default addons uses the 'apparel/electronics/powertools' catalogs and stores. But in my final project I dont want those stuff in it. Any idea here?

Comment: yes , in this case i propose to copy the addon into your own project under custom foler and then handle it as a own addon.