# Customizing Hybris accelerator storefront controllers in an addon

Tags: spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm using **Hybris 6.3** and would like to follow the best practice of customizing the accelerator storefront controllers using an addon.  This is done to make upgrading to a newer storefront much easier.

For example, the accelerator defines a Minicart controller similar to

```java
package com.custom.storefront.controllers.misc;

@Controller
public class MiniCartController extends AbstractController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/cart/miniCart/{totalDisplay:.*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMiniCart(@PathVariable final String totalDisplay, final Model model)
    {
        //default functionality
    }
}
```

In my addon, I would like to map that same URL pattern to a new controller that will override the functionality.

```java
package com.custom.storefrontaddon.controllers.misc;

@Controller
public class MyCustomMiniCartController extends AbstractController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/cart/miniCart/{totalDisplay:.*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMiniCart(@PathVariable final String totalDisplay, final Model model)
    {
        //overriding functionality, different from the default accelerator storefront
    }
}
```

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993565/how-can-customize-addons-in-hybris), and the accepted advice was to do as follows:

- In *addon-web-spring.xml*, override the controller bean like

```xml
    <bean name="miniCartController" class="com.custom.storefrontaddon.controllers.misc.MyCustomMiniCartController"/>
```

- In *addon-web-spring.xml*, add a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` like

```xml
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/cart/miniCart/**">miniCartController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

- The addon controller will now be called instead of the default accelerator controller for the target URL.

## My Question

How does this mechanism work when the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-31-vs-30) explicitly says that

> There are also several things no longer possible:
>   - Select a controller first with a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` or `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` and then narrow the method based on `@RequestMapping` annotations.

Spring is using `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` by default in the accelerator storefront, and in the addon we are introducing `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`. I want to understand why this works, when every other forum post I've read says that you cannot override `@RequestMapping` URLs in a different controller, or you will get an exception thrown for the duplicate URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my answer, I will suppopse that you made a typo, and you meant MyCustomMiniCartController instead of MiniCartController in:

```
<bean name="miniCartController" class="com.custom.storefrontaddon.controllers.misc.MyCustomMiniCartController"/>
```

The thing here is that `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` has nothing to do and its declaration in 
`addon-web-spring.xml` is completely useless.

Redefining the `miniCartController` bean in the addon makes the bean definition overridden by the addon class, and so the request mapping that is declared in the addon class is the one "used" by the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`.

Comment: It is strange that SAP's own addons that override a controller bean also define `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` with the relevant URL patterns, and some attach interceptors to it as well.  A couple of examples are b2ctelcocheckoutaddon and subscriptionstorefront (interceptor attached). As you pointed out, the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` is defined after the definition of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and so Spring would consult them for mapping resolution in order of definition and the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` would never be consulted because `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` can return a match.

Comment: If you agree on the explanation and tested it successfully, could be please accept the answer?