# How to customize b2bacceleratoraddon addon

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, add-on, accelerator

I need to change some code in **b2bacceleratoraddon**, but I don't want to change the standard code.

Is there any standard way to copy the addon with a new custom addon? or should I change standard code?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993565/how-can-customize-addons-in-hybris/47012407#47012407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its depends on what you want to override?

**Approach 1:**
Override functionality using your custom addon, For example [this](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b490bb4e85bc42a7aa09d513d0bcb18e/1905/en-US/8acfaf1186691014af82b18f46e90f49.html)

**Approach 2:** Use the customize folder
If you have small change and you need quick fix, I think you can use this approach. All you need to do is create a customize folder under the config folder and place your customized file there with the same folder structure and name as OOTB. Then you need to run `ant customize`(This internally replace OOTB files with the customized file from the customize folder)

e.g. If you have a small fix/change in the  **AssistedServiceComponentController.java** of acceleratoraddon, then you can copy the file, make your changes and place at below mentioned path and run ant customize

```
\config\customize\ext-addon\assistedservicestorefront\acceleratoraddon\web\src\de\hybris\platform\assistedservicestorefront\controllers\cms\AssistedServiceComponentController.java
```

**Approach 3:** Create custom addon using OOTB addon as the template
You can make the current OOTB addon as the template and run `ant extgen` to generate your custom addon making the OOTB addon as the base template. Refer [this](http://www.hybriscx.com/sap-hybris/hybris-generate-addon-from-another-addon-crack/).

Be mindful here, as you will not get new functionality or changes when you upgrade your platform.

Comment: Thanks for your precious reply

Yes, i need some quick fix, so i think that i will choose approch n° 2.

Thanks for your help!