# Overwrite B2BAcceleratorProductAddToCartComponentRender in b2b2acceleratoraddon from another addon

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How can I overwrite the B2BAcceleratorProductAddToCartComponentRender from my addon. I need to replace some JSP and the only way I see is to overwrite this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the bean definition of B2BAcceleratorProductAddToCartComponentRender and override in spring.xml in your addon.

Comment: thanks when I try it, I have the problem that it doesn't find the parent: addOnJspIncludeCMSComponentRenderer from addonsupport, but I added it to the localextensions and other places

Comment: Did you use the *web-spring.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Addons are a tricky stuff in hybris. I had create also a question about 'how work with addons':

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407943/hybris-addons-install-uninstall-concept)

[here](https://help.hybris.com/6.5.0/hcd/8ac4edc486691014af43e39b142bc29a.html) are some information about the b2bacceleratoraddon itself.

[here](https://help.hybris.com/6.5.0/hcd/8ad05d17866910148d06e408f617dd40.html) are some information customizing with addons